# Spark Application Not Recovering when Executor Lost

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm running Spark in a standalone cluster. A python driver application on the same node as Master and 2 worker nodes.  The business logic is python code that is run by the executors created on the Worker nodes.

I'm ending up in a situation where nothing progresses if one of the executors dies. If I forcibly kill one of the backend processes on Worker 0, Master outputs:

```
16/06/07 16:20:35 ERROR TaskSchedulerImpl: Lost executor 1 on sparkslave0: Remote RPC client disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues. Check driver logs for WARN messages.
16/06/07 16:20:35 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 2.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 2, sparkslave0): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 1 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Remote RPC client disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues. Check driver logs for WARN messages.
16/06/07 16:20:35 INFO DAGScheduler: Executor lost: 1 (epoch 0)
16/06/07 16:20:35 INFO AppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor updated: app-20160607161937-0010/1 is now EXITED (Command exited with code 137)
16/06/07 16:20:35 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Executor app-20160607161937-0010/1 removed: Command exited with code 137
```

then, after a timeout:

```
16/06/07 16:22:35 WARN NettyRpcEndpointRef: Error sending message [message = RemoveExecutor(1)] in 1 attempts
org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeoutException: Futures timed out after [120 seconds]. This timeout is controlled by spark.rpc.askTimeout
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.org$apache$spark$rpc$RpcTimeout$$createRpcTimeoutException(RpcTimeout.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$addMessageIfTimeout$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$addMessageIfTimeout$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:59)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:33)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:76)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEndpointRef.askWithRetry(RpcEndpointRef.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEndpointRef.askWithRetry(RpcEndpointRef.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManagerMaster.tell(BlockManagerMaster.scala:225)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManagerMaster.removeExecutor(BlockManagerMaster.scala:40)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleExecutorLost(DAGScheduler.scala:1321)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1628)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1599)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1588)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [120 seconds]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:219)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.result(Promise.scala:223)
    at scala.concurrent.Await$$anonfun$result$1.apply(package.scala:107)
    at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$DefaultBlockContext$.blockOn(BlockContext.scala:53)
    at scala.concurrent.Await$.result(package.scala:107)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:75)
    ... 9 more
```

I can see that the Worker daemon has created another executor but nothing happens.  After 3 attempts, I see

```
16/06/07 16:26:41 ERROR Inbox: Ignoring error
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Error notifying standalone scheduler's driver endpoint
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend.removeExecutor(CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend.scala:362)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.SparkDeploySchedulerBackend.executorRemoved(SparkDeploySchedulerBackend.scala:144)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.client.AppClient$ClientEndpoint$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(AppClient.scala:186)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Inbox$$anonfun$process$1.apply$mcV$sp(Inbox.scala:116)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Inbox.safelyCall(Inbox.scala:204)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Inbox.process(Inbox.scala:100)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Dispatcher$MessageLoop.run(Dispatcher.scala:215)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Error sending message [message = RemoveExecutor(1,Command exited with code 137)]
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEndpointRef.askWithRetry(RpcEndpointRef.scala:118)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEndpointRef.askWithRetry(RpcEndpointRef.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend.removeExecutor(CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend.scala:359)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeoutException: Cannot receive any reply in 120 seconds. This timeout is controlled by spark.rpc.askTimeout
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.org$apache$spark$rpc$RpcTimeout$$createRpcTimeoutException(RpcTimeout.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$addMessageIfTimeout$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$addMessageIfTimeout$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:59)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:33)
    at scala.util.Failure$$anonfun$recover$1.apply(Try.scala:185)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:161)
    at scala.util.Failure.recover(Try.scala:185)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recover$1.apply(Future.scala:324)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recover$1.apply(Future.scala:324)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32)
    at org.spark-project.guava.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$SameThreadExecutorService.execute(MoreExecutors.java:293)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.ExecutionContextImpl$$anon$1.execute(ExecutionContextImpl.scala:133)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.executeWithValue(Promise.scala:40)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete(Promise.scala:248)
    at scala.concurrent.Promise$class.complete(Promise.scala:55)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.complete(Promise.scala:153)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Future.scala:235)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Future.scala:235)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$InternalCallbackExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.processBatch$1(Future.scala:643)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$InternalCallbackExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(Future.scala:658)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$InternalCallbackExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Future.scala:635)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$InternalCallbackExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Future.scala:635)
    at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$.withBlockContext(BlockContext.scala:72)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$InternalCallbackExecutor$Batch.run(Future.scala:634)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$InternalCallbackExecutor$.scala$concurrent$Future$InternalCallbackExecutor$$unbatchedExecute(Future.scala:694)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$InternalCallbackExecutor$.execute(Future.scala:685)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.executeWithValue(Promise.scala:40)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete(Promise.scala:248)
    at scala.concurrent.Promise$class.tryFailure(Promise.scala:112)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryFailure(Promise.scala:153)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv$$anon$1.run(NettyRpcEnv.scala:241)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Cannot receive any reply in 120 seconds
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv$$anon$1.run(NettyRpcEnv.scala:242)
    ... 7 more
16/06/07 16:26:41 ERROR DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop: DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop failed; shutting down SparkContext
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Error sending message [message = RemoveExecutor(1)]
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEndpointRef.askWithRetry(RpcEndpointRef.scala:118)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEndpointRef.askWithRetry(RpcEndpointRef.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManagerMaster.tell(BlockManagerMaster.scala:225)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManagerMaster.removeExecutor(BlockManagerMaster.scala:40)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleExecutorLost(DAGScheduler.scala:1321)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1628)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1599)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1588)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeoutException: Futures timed out after [120 seconds]. This timeout is controlled by spark.rpc.askTimeout
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.org$apache$spark$rpc$RpcTimeout$$createRpcTimeoutException(RpcTimeout.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$addMessageIfTimeout$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$addMessageIfTimeout$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:59)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:33)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:76)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEndpointRef.askWithRetry(RpcEndpointRef.scala:101)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [120 seconds]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:219)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.result(Promise.scala:223)
    at scala.concurrent.Await$$anonfun$result$1.apply(package.scala:107)
    at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$DefaultBlockContext$.blockOn(BlockContext.scala:53)
    at scala.concurrent.Await$.result(package.scala:107)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:75)
    ... 9 more
16/06/07 16:26:41 INFO AppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor added: app-20160607161937-0010/2 on worker-20160607145945-192.168.33.100-34250 (192.168.33.100:34250) with 1 cores
16/06/07 16:26:41 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Granted executor ID app-20160607161937-0010/2 on hostPort 192.168.33.100:34250 with 1 cores, 1222.0 MB RAM
16/06/07 16:26:41 INFO AppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor updated: app-20160607161937-0010/2 is now RUNNING
16/06/07 16:26:41 INFO AppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor updated: app-20160607161937-0010/2 is now EXITED (Command exited with code 1)
16/06/07 16:26:41 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Executor app-20160607161937-0010/2 removed: Command exited with code 1
16/06/07 16:26:41 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Cancelling stage 0
16/06/07 16:26:41 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Stage 0 was cancelled
```

and the application fails.

Is anyone able to give any guidance on how to recover gracefully and allow the application to continue with the remaining and/or new executor?

Many thanks,

Dave

Comment: It looks like some network issue. The driver is trying to connect with the worker and it is not able to connect. Since there are only two worker nodes it will fail if it won't be able to connect any of them.I am not an administrator guy. But u  can refer to networking section of this link  if some property can help. https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#networking

Comment: Could you pls share you spark-submit command as well?